# How to return a float (or int) with a sanic API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sanic

I am creating a simple Sanic REST API but cannot figure out how return numeric data. After looking [at the docs](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/response.html), it appears that you can only return `json`, `html`, `text`, etc., but no `float` or `int`.

I am following the basic example in the docs, except have switched the return to a float:

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic()

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return 1.1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

However, it works perfectly if the return statement is `return json({"hello": "world"})`. Why can I not return a float? I can return it as `return text(1.1)`, but then does the client who calls it receive it as a `str` (as opposed to a `float`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just JSON your number.

```py
>>> import json
>>> s = json.dumps(543.34)
>>> s
'543.34'
>>> json.loads(s)
543.34
```

With Sanic:

```
from sanic import Sanic, response
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic()

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return response.json(1.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: If you mean to return the `json.dumps()` then the user will still receive it as JSON. Can I just send it as a float?

Comment: Well, you're using HTTP, not a hyper float transfer protocol